# iOS 7 Map user pin not updating location

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

I'm facing an issue with iOS 7 map user pin not updating.

My app is a tracking app that track the user's location as they drive:

[image]

(notice here, the standard iOS 7 white-blue user location pin should be where the red pin is)

The pin is the standard iOS user pin NOT a custom annotation.

In my app, when I press the start button, it calls:

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and when I press the stop button, it calls:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

However, I believe MapKit's user location pin should always update automatically to show the user's location regardless of whether I have called startUpdatingLocation on my CLLocationManager right?

If I don't press the "start" button in my app, the user location pin moves as expected. It's just when I do press it that it stops moving.

In iOS 6, the user location pin behave as expected even if I do press the start button.

Is there something about MapKit user location pin in iOS7 that was changed?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue in one of my apps. I don't know why the mapview in IOS7 behaves this way.
But I've found a solution to this problem. You need to set the userTrackingMode property of the mapview to MKUserTrackingModeFollow:

```
[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];
```

After that, it should update the userLocation pin!

Comment: I had this line before: [geoMap setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES]; in previous version of app but I also changed it to [geoMap setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow]; just to test but still same problem, the user location icon still not updating =/